# highcharts hover.state.halo color malfunction?

Tags: colors, highcharts

I have a simple problem with hover's halo effect.

Indeed if I use a donut chart with default colors:

http://jsfiddle.net/8n655/1/

The first and second color have a good hover effect but if I use custom colors:

```
{
    "colors":["#3ca6af","#aaa"],
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8n655/2/

The first data work well, but on the gray, the hover effect is broken...

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the custom color you mention change the color code such that it has six digits after '#'.

when opacity is applied #aaa is behaving differently and opacity is not applied. so change it as  #aaaaaa.

```
"colors":["#3ca6af","#aaaaaa"],
```

I've updated your fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/8n655/4/